# Cannot convert return expression of type to return type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type')

Tags: swift

I am trying to generate watermark with PDFKit
I have got the official code
But I want to make his writing more dynamic
Allows me to enter the watermark text
But I have some problems with return AnyClass
Watermark code

```
import Foundation
import PDFKit


class WatermarkPage: PDFPage {

    var watermark : NSString 
    
    init(watermark : NSString) {

        self.watermark = watermark
        super.init()
        
    }
    
    override func draw(with box: PDFDisplayBox, to context: CGContext) {

        super.draw(with: box, to: context)

        UIGraphicsPushContext(context)
        context.saveGState()

        
        let pageBounds = self.bounds(for: box)

        context.translateBy(x: pageBounds.size.width, y: pageBounds.size.height)
        context.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        
        
        let string3: NSString = watermark
        let attributes3: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1),
            NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 12)
        ]
         
        string3.draw(at: CGPoint(x: -250, y: 750), withAttributes: attributes3)
        



        context.restoreGState()
        UIGraphicsPopContext()

    }
```

Here is where I encountered the problem

```
internal func classForPage() -> AnyClass {
        
        let page = WatermarkPage(watermark: "Test text")
        return page.self

    }
```

Comment: Hi, could you let me know if my answer helps? If it does, could you please mark it as accepted by clicking the ✓ at the left my my answer? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Swift `AnyClass` is an alias of `AnyObject.Type`, you might want to try using just `AnyObject` here:

```swift
internal func classForPage() -> AnyObject {   
    let page = WatermarkPage(watermark: "Test text")
    return page.self
}
```